# How to record a script using jmeter for capturing the webservice requests that occurs between two applications?

Tags: jmeter

How to record a script using jmeter for capturing the webservice requests that occurs between two applications ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-jmeter-to-record-test-scenarios.  Specifically, the information on how to set up the proxy for Firefox.  You have to make requests through a proxy at 127.0.0.1:8080 or localhost:8080.

Answer (score 0):

Configure both applications or underlying application server, or underlying Java Virtual Machine or underlying operating system to use host, running JMeter as a proxy and it will record all the requests between applications.

You can use [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide as a reference.

For more information on JMeter Proxy Server configuration see:

- [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder User Manual Entry](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
- [JMeter Proxy Step by Step PDF](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf) guide